# Android - Rest Post Call

Tags: android, rest, http, post

I am having a bit of trouble making a post call to a rest api. When using the Chrome Advanced Rest Client, I use the URL : http://example.com/task_manager/v1/register to test and that works fine. I'm trying to get users to be able to register through android. When I click my button, I'm not seeing any changes to the database.

I'm calling the method through xml  `android:onClick="register"`

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    public EditText enterEmail;
    public EditText enterPassword;
    public EditText forgotPassword;
    public ImageButton loginButton;
    public ImageButton RegisterButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //hide status bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
        enterEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailentry);
        enterPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordentry);
        forgotPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.forgotpass);
        //login
        loginButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

        //register
        RegisterButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);

    }

    public void login(View view){

    }

    public void register(View view){
        String email = enterEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = enterPassword.getText().toString();
        String name = "ANDROID";
        String apiURL = "http://example.com/task_manager/v1/register";

        if( (email != null && !email.isEmpty()) && (password != null && !password.isEmpty()) && (name != null && !name.isEmpty())) {

            String urlString = apiURL + "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&password="+password;

            new CallAPI().execute(urlString);

        }
    }



    private class CallAPI extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String urlString=params[0]; // URL to call

            String resultToDisplay = "";

            InputStream in = null;

            // HTTP Get
            try {

                URL url = new URL(urlString);

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            } catch (Exception e ) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                return e.getMessage();

            }

            return resultToDisplay;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

    } // end CallAPI
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by rewriting the class to use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

For appending request parameters shouldn't the end url be like the following:

String apiURL = "http://example.com/task_manager/v1/register?";

Answer (score 1):

If the focus of your question is on making a POST request you need to set the request method prior to your call to getInputStream.

You need to call urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST") after you call url.openConnection().

As Jayesh mentions it appears your URL is incorrect also.